# How to get slack notification when a certain step passes / fails in bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, slack, bitbucket-pipelines

I have E2E tests in one of the bitbucket repository and I created a docker image to run those tests in another repository. I am able to run the tests using image but I also want to get the slack notifications when the certain E2E step in the pipeline passes / fails.

I don't want to get slack notifications for the whole pipeline. I just want it for the e2e tests when they run in other repositories.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort it by having after script:

```
after-script:
          - echo $BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE
          - BUILD_STATUS="successful"
  

        - if [[ BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE -eq 0]]; then exit 0; else 
BUILD_STATUS="failed"; fi 
              - echo "Step ${BUILD_STATUS}"
              - pipe: atlassian/slack-notify:2.0.0
                variables:
                  WEBHOOK_URL: $WEBHOOK_URL
                  MESSAGE: The E2E tests are "${BUILD_STATUS}".
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).